# How to perform an action before redirect in OpenID-Connect OWIN MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, openid-connect

I am trying this for days, but not able to figure it out, if some can help me , will be appreciated.

```
public void SignIn()
        {
            // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                //Perform some action if user is successfully authenticated??

                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44309/DummyController/DummyAction" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the action RedirectToIdentityProvider

```
  Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
            }

   private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, 
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> arg)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```